# On which conditions will view modifier code get called? view modifier isn't rendered

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-charts

I have a view modifier which sets the xdomain of a chart. I had this code littered all over the place (multiple charts), so instead tried to consolidate the code.

For some reason it doesn't get called when the chart is rendered when the code is part of the view modifier.

functioning (scattered to each chart) code which updates when chart is updated:

```
struct MyChart: View {
  var body: some View {
      Chart {
        .... chart stuff...
      }
      .chartXScale(domain: xdomain())
  }
// this will be called time the chart is rendered
  func xdomain() -> ClosedRange<Date> {
        let now = Date()
        let lower = now.addingTimeInterval(-180)
        let x = lower...now
        return x
    }
}
```

No functioning - The chart domain isn't udpated each time the chart updates - only the first time does it get set

```
struct DomainModifer: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.chartXScale(domain: xdomain())
    }
    
    
}

extension View {
    func xdomain() -> some View {
        modifier(DomainModifer())
    }
}

func xdomain() -> ClosedRange<Date> {
    let now = Date()
    let lower = now.addingTimeInterval(-180)
    let x = lower...now
    return x
}


struct MyChart: View {
  var body: some View {
      Chart {
        .... chart stuff...
      }
      .xdomain() // doesn't update
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, SwiftUI would run `body` to find the dependencies (e.g. `@State`, `@Binding`, `@ObservedObject`) of a view. When any of the dependencies change, `body` is run again to find out what has changed and SwiftUI updates the view according to that. The same applies to `ViewModifier`s too, with `body(content:)`.

SwiftUI doesn't treat `Date()` as a "dependency". It doesn't make sense for SwiftUI tried to update the view every time `Date()` changes, after all. When the chart is updated, SwiftUI sees that none of the dependencies of `DomainModifer` has changed (it literally has no dependencies!), so it doesn't call `body(content:)`.

The first code snippet works because when the chart updates, `MyChart.body` is executed, and in there you call `xdomain()`, so `xdomain()` is called for every update to `MyChart`.

The simplest way to fix this would be to not use a `ViewModifier`. Just put all the code in the `View` extension:

```
extension View {
    // the View extension method and the method that generates a range 
    // should have different names
    func xDomain() -> some View {
        chartXScale(xdomain())
    }
}
```

Now `xdomain()` will be called whenever you call `xDomain()`, which you do in `body`.

You can also keep using the `ViewModifier`, but the `ClosedRange<Date>` should be passed from the `View` extension.

```
extension View {
    // the View extension method and the method that generates a range 
    // should have different names
    func xDomain() -> some View {
        modifier(DomainModifer(domain: xdomain()))
    }
}
```